# Is this equality true

Tags: integration

Is the following equality true?

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x+1}{3x+4} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{3x+4}+\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{3x+4}$$

Comment: None of the integrals converges. They all diverge to $\infty$, so whether one says there is equality is a matter of taste.

Comment: How do you prove $\infty=\infty + \infty$?

Comment: Maybe, if we prove that it's true for all natural number upper limits using induction, and consider $\infty$ to be a natural number? I am not sure if this is right though

Comment: but in general can integration be separated into two integrals?

Comment: Quick answer: No, if some of the integrals diverge.

Answer (score -1):

$$ \int ( f(x) + g(x))dx = \int f(x) dx + \int g(x)dx$$

So, your equality is correct.

---

[Wiki article]

1. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_integration

Comment: This is only true if the integrals converge.